# CA2140. Transparent code must not reference security critical items

Tags: c#, .net, security, .net-4.0

I marked my assembly as security transparent with

```
[assembly: SecurityTransparent]
```

In this assembly I have a class with a method as following:

```
class BitmapLoader
{
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    private static Bitmap fromStream(Stream stream)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Why `SecuritySafeCritical` attribute applied to `fromStream` method does not prevent Code Analysis from reporting the following error?

> CA2140 Transparent code must not reference security critical items
>
> Transparent method 'BitmapLoader.fromStream(Stream)' references
>   security critical method 'Marshal.Copy(byte[], int, IntPtr, int)'.
>
> In order for this reference to be allowed under the security
>   transparency rules, either 'BitmapLoader.fromStream(Stream)' must
>   become security critical or safe-critical, or 'Marshal.Copy(byte[],
>   int, IntPtr, int)' become security safe-critical or transparent.

What have I missed? And how should I fix the error?

Comment: Try once to make your class [SecurityCrititcal]

Answer (score 0):

your code is treated as `Transparent`:

> Transparent method 'BitmapLoader.fromStream(Stream)'

in large assemblies it is possible, that you have anywhere unwillingly set the `SecurityTransparent` attribute. 
I found this unwillingly attribute by entering `[assembly: SecurityTransparent]` in AssemblyInfo.cs and rebuild the assembly. An error of double SecurityTransparent Attributes show me the statement, which is to delete. Then it works as exspected.

Comment: The question of the OP was: _Why SecuritySafeCritical attribute applied to fromStream method does not prevent Code Analysis from reporting the following error?_ And the answer is: There is anywhere `[assembly: SecurityTransparent]` in the code. My answer described, how to find that.

Comment: You changed your answer after it was flagged. Now it is indeed good while it wasn't before.

Answer (score 0):

Applying `SecurityTransparentAttribute` to the assembly forces all its code to become transparent, regardless of any type- or member-level transparency attributes.  In theory, you should also be getting a [CA2136](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264493.aspx) violation for the `fromStream` method to let you know about this problem.